# “Warning: Could not start Excel server for export. XLSWRITE will attempt to write file in CSV format. > In xlswrite (line 174)

Tags: excel, matlab, xlsx

i have problem with my code that i try to save data in to excel format. i run matlab under linux. why everytime i try to save data into ecel format warning always show and myfile ist not excel file but .csv file, the meessage is 
“Warning: Could not start Excel server for export. XLSWRITE will attempt to write file in CSV format. > In xlswrite (line 174)”